# select element in jsoup with attributes empty value

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code. I want to retrieve elements whose attribute style is empty value.

```
String html = "<div style=''>dsfsdfs</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements elements = doc.select("*[style='']"); 

System.out.println(elements.size());
```

But at the output i didn't get the size of elements whose style attribute is empty.

Comment: what about `doc.select("[style='']");` without *?

Comment: @gigadot : when you place * it select all elements whose attribute is style. ex div with style > div[style]. so *[style].

Comment: i know that but you don't need to add * if you want all the elements that has style attribute. i'm just wondering if it is a bug, which is unlikely but worth trying.

Comment: also, your code cannot be compiled on the first line because of the double quote.

Comment: yes in that you are right it is working without * but what about the attribute like style="" so i want to fetch that kind of elements

Comment: how about `doc.select("[style=''],[style=\"\"]");`?

Comment: not working regarding doc.select("[style=''],[style=\"\"]");

Answer (score 3):

Not shure if you can select elements by empty attribute values.

But you can select all elements with `style` attribute and check their values:

```
String html = "<div style=''>dsfsdfs</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


for( Element element : doc.select("[style]") )
{
    if( element.attr("style").isEmpty() )
    {
        // Do something with 'element'
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

### Edit:

```
Elements emptyAttr = doc.select("[style~=^$]");
```

Comment: you right but i want to fetch it without loop. so i need it to place in doc.select(whatever);

Comment: I see! Check my edit, this should work.